# Iterating over data without saving it

Tags: java, iterator

I would like to write simple program which can offer me feature to print n even numbers starting from some firstNumber. Its number is totalNumber. I don't want to save them, just print them. This is my piece of code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class EvenNumbers implements Iterable<Integer>{

    private int firstNumber;
    private int totalNumbers;

    public EvenNumbers(int firstNumber, int totalNumbers) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.totalNumbers = totalNumbers;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new myNewIterator();
    }

    private static class myNewIterator implements Iterator<Integer>{

        private int firstNumber;
        private int totalNumbers;
        private int tmp;

        public myNewIterator() {
            this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
            this.totalNumbers = totalNumbers;

            this.tmp = firstNumber - 2;
        }   

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(totalNumbers > 0){
                totalNumbers--;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            return tmp + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

And Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EvenNumbers en = new EvenNumbers(14, 4);

        for (Integer n : en) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }

    }

}
```

As may you can see, I don't get any output for this program.
Can someone explain me what I doing wrong?
Many thanks!

Comment: "public mojNoviIterator()" ??? is this code compiling. plz correct it

Comment: Does the code compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fafl [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34798562/5039001) is a better and concise answer.

**To point out why this code was not working:**

**1. The problem is with your myNewIterator constructor**. You were assigning the variable with itself. Also as default value of int is zero and your iteration condition if(totalNumbers > 0) will always fail.

```
public myNewIterator() {
        /** these two lines have to be changed**/ 
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
        this.totalNumbers = totalNumbers;
        /** end **/

        this.tmp = firstNumber - 2;
}
```

You have to take these two values from constructor. Following is the corrected code. I have corrected the constructor name as well.

**2. you must not decrement totalNumbers in hasNext() method** because say there is a only one next element if I call hasNext() 100 times without calling next() it should still return true i.e. it has next element. So decrement should happen when next() is called.

**3. tmp must be updated for every next() call**.

These changes also are reflected in following code.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class EvenNumbers implements Iterable<Integer>{

private int firstNumber;
private int totalNumbers;

public EvenNumbers(int firstNumber, int totalNumbers) {
    this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
    this.totalNumbers = totalNumbers;
}

@Override
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    /***** changed *****/ 
    return new myNewIterator(this.firstNumber,this.totalNumbers);
}

private static class myNewIterator implements Iterator<Integer>{

    private int firstNumber;
    private int totalNumbers;
    private int tmp;

    /***** changed *****/ 
    public myNewIterator(int firstNo,int totalNo) {
         /***** changed *****/
        /****     edited these lines     *******/
        this.firstNumber = firstNo;
        this.totalNumbers = totalNo;
        /***** ****/

        this.tmp = firstNumber - 2;
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if(totalNumbers > 0){
            /***** changed *****/   
            //totalNumbers--; //commenting this line as repeated calls of this line makes this call unsafe
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        /***** changed *****/  
        totalNumbers--;
        tmp = tmp + 2
        return tmp;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have so much code?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start = 14;
        int count = 4;

        for (int n = start; n < start + 2 * count; n += 2) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like OP is doing an exercise on `Iterator`s and your solution does not give much help in this respect.

Comment: modify answer such that it gives an iterator